# In asymmetric encryption, is there a meaningful difference between the public and the private key?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, decryption, asymmetric, public-key

Is it possible to swap them, so that the public key is kept secret while the private key is public? Or do they actually function differently?

Thinking specifically about DSA though I'm interested if there is a general answer.

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52495/can-rsa-keys-be-swapped

Comment: No, they can't be swapped, because [the private key contains the public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301302/does-rsa-private-key-always-contain-the-public-key-or-is-it-just-net).

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/167298/rsa-digital-signatures-vs-encryption-with-the-private-key